# java.lang.NullPointerException into a RecycleView implementation

Tags: java, android, android-room

Estaba desarrollando una App en Android con Java en la que conecto con una BBDD local para recuperar una descripcion y la url de una imagen, la cual después pretendo pintar en un recycleView.

El itemlist que utiliza el RecycleView tiene dos compoentes un TextView, y una IMageView, donde pretendo cargar la lista de los objetos almacenados en la BBDD.

Mi problema viene al intentar recuperar los datos de la BBDD local y tratar de recuperarlo en un Objeto que almacena los datos de la BBDD.

```
2021-04-27 11:16:41.252 15618-15618/com.example.journal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.journal, PID: 15618
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3738)
        at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3725)
        at com.example.journal.ui.journal.JournalFragment.updateUi(JournalFragment.java:160)
        at com.example.journal.ui.journal.JournalFragment.requestBirds(JournalFragment.java:150)
        at com.example.journal.ui.journal.JournalFragment.onViewCreated(JournalFragment.java:131)
```

El código del fragment donde hago la consulta y trato de pintarlo, es el siguiente:

JournalFragment.fragment

```
package com.example.journal.ui.journal;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.journal.R;
import com.example.journal.SQLiteImplementation.BirdRoom;
import com.example.journal.SQLiteImplementation.Birddb;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.journal.R.id.item_imgDiario;


public class JournalFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recycleView;
    private JournalViewModel mViewModel;
    private TextView txtTitulo, txtHora;
    private ImageView itemJornal;
    private BirdRoom[] birds;
    private List<BirdRoom> birdList;
    public static JournalFragment newInstance() {
        return new JournalFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_journal, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //birds = new List<BirdRoom>();

        itemJornal = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_imgDiario);
        txtTitulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTituloDiario);
        txtHora = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtHora);
        // RECOVER THE DATA FROM THE CAPTURE FRAGMENT.
        //TODO: Creo que lo que recupere el Jornal debeía ser desde la BBDD local de Room, ya que desde un Bundle siempre va a llegar Null.
        //TODO: Crear uno hilo para hacer la consulta a la BBDD.

        //Set the hour.
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hora, minutos, segundos,dia, mes, annio;
        String mes_string;
        hora =calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+2;
        minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        segundos = calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DATE);
        annio = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        switch (mes){
            case 1:
                mes_string = "ENERO";
                break;
            case 2:
                mes_string = "FEBRERO";
                break;
            case 3:
                mes_string = "MARZO";
                break;
            case 4:
                mes_string = "ABRIL";
                break;
            case 5:
                mes_string = "MAYO";
                break;
            case 6:
                mes_string = "JUNIO";
                break;
            case 7:
                mes_string = "JULIO";
                break;
            case 8:
                mes_string = "AGOSTO";
                break;
            case 9:
                mes_string = "SEPTIEMBRE";
                break;
            case 10:
                mes_string = "OCTUBRE";
                break;
            case 11:
                mes_string = "NOVIEMBRE";
                break;
            case 12:
                mes_string = "DICIEMBRE";
                break;
            default:
                mes_string = "";
        }

        txtHora.setText(hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos + " - " + dia + " " + mes_string + " " +  annio);
        itemJornal = (ImageView) view.findViewById(item_imgDiario);
        //itemJornal.setImageDrawable(null);

        /*
                //TODO: PROBAR A INSERTAR UNA INSTANCIA DE BIRDROOM EN LA BBDD PARA VER SI ES PORQUE NO TIENE DATOS.

         */

                //TODO: SE QUEDA LA UI COLGADA PORUQE PETA EL MAIN-THREAD

                //Set the Looper for the Toast.
        if(Looper.getMainLooper()==null){
            Looper.prepareMainLooper();
            }
        //birds = new BirdRoom[100];
        requestBirds(view);
        }



    private void requestBirds(View view) {
        Birddb bd = Birddb.getDatabase(getContext());
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                birds = bd.birdDAO().loadAllBirds();
            }
        });
        //Recover the data from Room bbdd.
        //TODO: Cargar el recycleView en otro hilo, que no se el MainThread.

        updateUi(view);

    }



    private void updateUi(View view) {

        //TODO: SOLUCIONAR NULLPOINTER: EL BIRDLIST LLEGA A NULL, AUNQUE AL DEBUGEARLO, NO PARECE QUE LO SEA.

        birdList = Arrays.asList(birds);
        if(!birdList.isEmpty() && birdList!=null){

            recycleView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
            recycleView.setAdapter(new RecycleViewAdapter(birdList, getContext()));

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se dispone de ninguna foto actualmente en su diario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Si sabeís por dodne van los tiros muchas gracias de ante mano!

Comment: El error te da toda la información: la función `asList` no funciona si le pasas un `null`. Tu  array `birds` es null cuando entras en la función `updateUi`. En la función `requestBirds`, ejecutas **asincronamente** la consulta a la BBDD y eso tarda y es asincrono, así que terminará cuando tenga que terminar. Pero tu función sigue y ejecuta `updateUi` antes de tiempo. Tendrás que llamar a `updateUi` cuando ya tengas la respuesta de la base de datos.

Comment: Osea que el problema esq se llama a UpdateUi antes de que haya terminado la consulta a la BBDD, asi que como podría controlar ese evento??

Comment: Pues tendrás que replantear tu diseño de forma que tengas en cuenta que hay cosas que se ejecutan de forma asíncrona. Puedes actualizar cuando termina la ejecución de loadAllBirds(), o puedes ahí levantar un flag y tener controlado eso en tu thread principal. Incluso podrías poner un espere por favor... Hay muchas opciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "EL BIRDLIST LLEGA A NULL, AUNQUE AL DEBUGEARLO, NO PARECE QUE LO
> SEA."

Lo que sucede es que al realizar debugging detienes la ejecución de este método y probablemente cuando analizas el valor de `birds`, esta variable ya tiene valor diferente a null.

La forma en como usas el [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) no indica cuando se termino de obtener una respuesta por lo tanto podrías estar llamando `updateUi(view)` cuando aún no tienes datos:

```
   ...
   Birddb bd = Birddb.getDatabase(getContext());
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            birds = bd.birdDAO().loadAllBirds();
        }
    });

    //Tal vez no tengas datos aún....
    updateUi(view);
    ...
    ...
```

Cambia tu [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) para que puedas obtener los datos en `doInBackground()` y posteriormente cargarlos y actualizar tu UI en `onPostExecute()`:

```
   AsyncTask<String, Void, BirdRoom[]> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, BirdRoom[]>() {
        @Override
        protected BirdRoom[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                //Obtiene datos.
                birds = bd.birdDAO().loadAllBirds();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return birds;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(BirdRoom[] birds) {
            //Actualiza UI.
            updateUi(view);
        };
    };

    task.execute();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ciertamente es lo que necesitaba el método onPostExcute para solucionar el problema que comentabais. Efectivamente al implementarlo como comentas se ha solucionado.